# Understanding how to Parse JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I appreciate there are many posts on this, and much on google, but I'm struggling to understand how to break up a JSON stream, and access the data.

I have a simple JSON response:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature",
"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.4211908, 37.7564513]},
"properties": {
"id": "2950648771574984913",
"accuracyInMeters": 80,
"timeStamp": 1309323032,
"reverseGeocode": "San Francisco, CA, USA",
"photoUrl": "https://www.google.com/latitude/apps/badge/api?type=photo&photo=uuRL2jABAAA.9fWeRzNpS-tdX0cqHxxclg.7zdBNW-Rb634EIkOgyO8sw",
"photoWidth": 96,
"photoHeight": 96,
"placardUrl": "https://www.google.com/latitude/apps/badge/api?type=photo_placard&photo=uuRL2jABAAA.9fWeRzNpS-tdX0cqHxxclg.7zdBNW-Rb634EIkOgyO8sw&moving=true&stale=true&lod=1&format=png",
"placardWidth": 56,
"placardHeight": 59
}
}
]
}
```

I'm trying to get access to all of the data in it, such as:

The two coordinates.
The reverseGeocode.
etc.

I've built a function like this:

```
    function findTristan(){
            var FindUrl = "/proxy.php";

            var tristanData = $.getJSON(FindUrl,function(json){});

            // this is the part I have failed to get right.
            alert(tristanData.coordinates);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX you need to manipulate the data only inside the success callback as that's the only place where this data is available. The `$.getJSON` function returns immediately and it doesn't return the result of the AJAX request. So the anonymous callback you left empty in your code should be used:

```
function findTristan() {
    var FindUrl = '/proxy.php';
    $.getJSON(FindUrl, function(json) {
        var lat = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
        var lon = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
        alert('lat: ' + lat + ', lon: ' + lon);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats a really helpful example, thank you for taking the time to make it so clear.

Comment: What would the syntax be for accessing the data in the properties section of the JSON, such as the reverseGeocode?

Comment: @Tristan, you may try this: `json.features[0].properties.reverseGeocode`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `$.parseJSON` function to transform your JSON into a js array : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Regards,

Max

Comment: I don't think you need this. If the server sends proper content type header (Content-Type: application/json) along with the JSON data, jQuery automatically parses it.

Answer (score 0):

These two should be used in your `getJSON` complete function.

```
json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1]
```

You shouldn't just `alert` after you issue an Ajax request. Why? Because Ajax call is asynchronous by nature. That simply means that request is send out and your code immediately continues its execution without waiting for the request to get a response. That's why your `alert` is executed (without any results of course) before you get results back from the server.

And also `getJSON` will not return data the way that you've done it. It will return data in its complete function where you'll have to consume  it yourself.

```
function findTristan(){
    var FindUrl = "/proxy.php";

    var tristanCoords = {};

    $.getJSON(FindUrl, function(data){

        tristanCoords = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
        alert("x: " + tristanCoords[0] + ", y: " + tristanCoords[1]);

    });
}
```

### Advice

Whenever you have to work with javascript, objects etc. use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) (Firefox plugin) and debug your code. You'll be ablle to drill down your object and exactly see its structure.